# R function to help manipulate dataframe by extracting data between two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I am working with a similar data frame and I am trying to take take the count of IDs for each SET values so that the final output will look like this.

```
123_a 2
123_b 2
221_a 1
221_b 1
```

I use table () but I am unable to get the count for SET specific. How can I crack this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `table` on the specific column 'Set' instead of the whole dataset with more columns

```
table(df1$Set)
```